# Movement of fingers expressing shyness

Tags: expressions, verbs

What is name of the action for when your fingers "caress" one another because you're shy?

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing. Could you include a picture? This may not be a gesture known to English speakers, one from another culture perhaps.

Comment: Are you talking about this?: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShyFingerTwiddling

Comment: I assure you it's quite common, at least in the West. But since I can't remember the term, finding a picture is being really difficult.

Comment: It's not twiddling, sorry. People do it in real life, but I don't know to to describe it in a good manner. The fingers will intertwine repeatedly, maybe messily, and you'll be looking at them as to avoid eye contact with the person or the group that causes you to be shy.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are referring to ***fidgeting***:

> to move about restlessly, nervously, or impatiently. – [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fidgeting)

> to make a lot of small movements because you are nervous, bored, etc. :
>   to move or act in a nervous or restless way – [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fidget)

Comment: That's not the one term I was looking for, but the meaning seems to be almost the same. Thank you ^^